# Is the Graveyard Really so Serious?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

Calculations in relation to black holes are solely in consideration of spacetime curvature and its effects. They are in total alienation with respect to the action of inertial agents[external forces].That world lines do not point outwards from a black hole is consistent with the fact that inertial agents are absent. Can the presence of inertial agents change the picture of the world lines?
Let's consider the following situation:

*An experimenter [source of "external forces" capable of producing non-geodesics] throws some mass into the black hole. Its surface area and volume increase.This is suggestive of outward world lines from the surface, causing the expansion----points on the surface should move outwards.The presence of "external forces" has modified the entire perspective of the situation.*

The black hole picture takes into consideration only the blackhole.*Right from the outset the black hole is considered in isolation from the rest of the universe.*
 Any type of modification due to the presence of external agents---artificial or natural ones do not figure in the blackhole calculations. Consideration of such factors can modify the picture of the   black hole.

Can technology prevent somebody near a black hole from falling into it? Can it remove the apprehensions of what we know to be a graveyard? .

Comment: Do you mean that adding extra stuff makes the black hole reject some matter? Sure--- if you drop some planet into a black hole, you can use the planets' to slingshot out of the black hole. What is the real question exactly?

Comment: The geometry prescribed by a metric creates certain paths called geodesics. In the presence of inertial interaction it is not mandatory that a body should follow such paths.In Schwarzschild's geometry we have radially inward geodesics.Rockets moving upwards do not follow such paths-------the spacetime path of a rocket[in some planet which has not undergone a collapse] is not a geodesic because of inertial interaction.In the collapsed condition also we have geodesics which point radially inwards.We may think of inertial interaction moving a body against these geodesics

Comment: By "inertial interaction" you mean rockets, I suppose. If you attach rockets to things, you can keep them from falling in. Why would the bodies make rockets after the collapse? You need some rockets. In my first comments I should have said "near a black hole, on the way in" instead of "into a black hole", I didn't mean inside the horizon.

Comment: You may consider the light cones in the following diagram:http://uofgts.com/Astro/graphics/stacks_image_104_1.png . These cones are "coordinate cones " constructed with the coordinate values of events.They pertain to an "Euclidean Background" viewed from curved spacetime.THe semivertical angles are different from 45 degrees. The coordinate speed of light [which is different from c] has been considered.

Comment: Everyone already has this in the head. What is the question here?

Comment: If some mass is thrown into a black-hole its surface area should increase.Volume is supposed to increase.Points on the surface must move outwards for the volume to increase. This is suggestive of outward world-lines when the black hole is getting modified.

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens--- the worldlines are drawn out by the gravity of the infalling matter, and the horizon expands in area as the matter crosses the horizon (or expands asymptotically as the matter mushes up on it, depending on your point of view).

Comment: The revised posting has not shown up at physics.stackexchange.com .Its already about 11/12 minutes. Is it going through a serious moderation?[Normally it does not take so much of time]

Comment: My last two revisions [30 min and 3 hour-old] have not shown up among the TOP questions to be accessed through physics.stackexchange.com. There has been a possible failure of the software this time. I have reported the matter at meta.

Comment: I will test the meta answer by upgrading the question.

Comment: Yes, smaller than -3 is the limit of appearance on top page.

Answer (score 1):

A Black Hole can be made to misbehave in an artificial manner. It may also "misbehave" due to natural reasons.

An experimenter may project charged mass into a black hole. If the charge [and the mass introduced ] maintain spherical symmetry, we now have the Reissner-Nordstrom metric instead of the Schwarzschild metric. That changes the basic nature of the "erstwhile" Black Hole.  It may not remain a Black hole any more. Introduction of charged matter from the external environment may be due to natural reasons also.

The basic aim would be to change the nature of the metric,somehow, any how.

The Black hole is serious but definitely not as serious as as we are inclined to believe in.

Comment: Its twelve minutes since I have posted the answer. It has not shown up in the TOP questions list to be accessed through physics.stackexchange.com . The software is quite "resolute" in not posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will address (again as a test of the answer in meta)

> Can technology prevent somebody near a black hole from falling into it? Can it remove the apprehensions of what we know to be a graveyard?

In much simpler graveyards, as for example the turbulence raised by the tsunami in Japan, we have seen huge boats falling in the swirl.  My advice to anybody going towards a black hole is to  *better change direction*  .  It is hardly conceivable that a human could leave a black hole if it has attracted him and his rocket, though maybe a calculation could be made with realistic masses to see how close to the horizon a rocket can orbit.

Comment: I had sent a mail at team+physics@stakexchange.com, informing them of the situation that the revised posting did not appear in the TOP question's list. The answer came:Ahh. Chances are you're just seeing a lag in the cache updating. It happens, and it can appear slow. Sometimes a refresh is all that is needed, sometimes it takes a bit more. I assure you, sir, that what you saw was likely perfectly normal." That was 14th May 10:54 AM ,Indian standard time.Later on further queries I was informed by email that low sore questions are not shown.That was 15 May,11:51 PM

Comment: Sorry to say that somebody brought your count down to -4 once again, so you are no longer on first page. If you go to the line with PHYSICS and click on QUESTIONS you will see your question.

Comment: I can access my postings from my "user page" by clicking on my name. But the important point is that the persons voting down a question should have some reason for the voting.does this come under any type of moderation?